# Datastax opsworks not installing agent on AWS

Tags: cassandra, datastax, aws-opsworks

I installed opsworks on one EC2 instance, and created three nodes in a cassandra cluster.

The agents on the nodes will not install and I get the following error

```
Install Errored: 'apt-get update' failed
exit status: 100

stderr:
W: Failed to fetch http://debian.datastax.com/enterprise/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages  401  Unauthorized [IP: 54.69.121.19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://debian.datastax.com/enterprise/dists/stable/main/binary-i386/Packages  401  Unauthorized [IP: 54.69.121.19 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Are you trying to install the agent from OpsCenter or manually using the deb package?  Also which version or DSE are you running?

Comment: Sorry I meant OpsCenter and yes I installed using the deb package by following this tutorial on an EC2 instance running ubuntu 14.04

Comment: http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-opsc/opsc/install/opscInstallDeb_t.html